# The smallest value of $|a|$ such that the lines $ x = a+m $, $y = -2 $ and $y = mx$ are concurrent

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, coordinate-systems

#### Question

If the line $ x = a+m $, $y = -2 $ and $y = mx$ are concurrent, the least value of $|a|$ is

> (A) $\sqrt{2}$
>   (B) $2\sqrt{2}$
>   (C) $2\sqrt{3}$
>   (D) $3\sqrt{2}$

#### Solution

Since the lines are concurrent $-2 = m(a +m)$ $\Rightarrow$ $m^2 + am  + 2 = 0 .$ Since $m$ is real, $a^2\ge 8,$ $|a| \ge 2\sqrt{2}.$ Hence least value of $|a|$ is $2\sqrt{2}.$

So my question is how $a^2 \ge 8$ was assigned the value. If anyone can please give a hint it would be helpful.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: oops i forgot that haha sorry i will edit it

Comment: @Akash: If you are editing your question you might as well find an appropriate title...

Comment: what title you suggest it is just a homework question of which one part i can't understand so what should be the tittle you suggest

Comment: @Akash Ideally we should know what your problem is just by looking at the title. Your current title tells you that you have some confusion on a homework question, but it doesn't state what that confusion is. That should be in the title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**: Do you know what the *discriminant* of a quadratic function is? In order for a quadratic to have real roots, the discriminant must be non-negative (and it must be positive for it to have distinct real roots).

Comment: yead i know that

Comment: What is the discriminant of $m^2+am+2$ (considered as a quadratic in $m$)? When is this nonnegative?

Comment: oh thank's man i got it know really thank you was just missing tha